# PHP returning [false] when I have not asked it too

Tags: php, json, printing

I am not sure why, But when I run the following code and there is nothing in the database I get the error [false] when I view the PHP page instead of the correct error message

```
public function fetchfriends($userid)
{
    $this->userid = $userid;
    $contact_check = mysql_query("
              SELECT *
              FROM user_contact
              WHERE from_userid = '{$this->userid}'
              AND approved   != 1
            ");


if(!mysql_num_rows($contact_check))
        {

                $arr = array("error" => "No Friends?<br/>Search above for New users or invite some friends.");
                print json_encode($arr);
        }
        else
        {
                $friendlook = mysql_query("
                    SELECT friend.to_userid,
                           info.username,
                           info.firstname,
                           info.lastname,
                           info.status,
                           astatus.onlinestatus

                    FROM      user_contact AS friend
                    LEFT JOIN user_info    AS info    ON friend.to_userid = info.id
                    LEFT JOIN user_online  AS astatus ON friend.to_userid = astatus.userid

                    WHERE friend.from_userid = '{$this->userid}'
                      AND friend.approved    = 1
                      AND friend.to_userid   = info.id

                    ORDER BY astatus.onlinestatus DESC
                ");

                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($friendlook);
                $rows[] = $row;
                print json_encode($rows);
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if anyone would know why?

Comment: You really should fix the indentation there, buddy. :) It really matters.

Comment: seems that you are trying to get values of lower query on condition applied to upper query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 SQL queries and you only check if the first has any results. The problem is that if the first has results and the second doesn't you will not get your error message, but the `[false]` you receive now.

Your code should look something like:

```
public function fetchfriends($userid)
{
    $this->userid = $userid;
    $contact_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_contact WHERE from_userid = '{$this->userid}' AND approved != 1");

    if(mysql_num_rows($contact_check))
    {
        $friendlook = mysql_query("SELECT friend.to_userid, info.username, info.firstname, info.lastname, info.status, astatus.onlinestatus FROM user_contact as friend LEFT JOIN user_info as info ON friend.to_userid = info.id LEFT JOIN user_online as astatus ON friend.to_userid = astatus.userid WHERE friend.to_userid = info.id AND friend.from_userid = '{$this->userid}' AND friend.approved = 1 ORDER BY astatus.onlinestatus DESC");

        if (mysql_num_rows($friendlook)) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($friendlook);
            $rows[] = $row;
            print json_encode($rows);
        } else {
            $arr = array("error" => "Your friends are not online");
            print json_encode($arr);
        }

        return;
    }

    $arr = array("error" => "No Friends?<br/>Search above for New users or invite some friends.");
    print json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: One more thing: use SELECT COUNT(*) instead of SELECT *

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

> Return Values:
>   Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows."

Your select statement returns `0` rows, `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false`, you insert that false value into `$rows`, so you get an array containing a single false value.

Use `if($row === false)` or `if($row)` to detect if you received a valid row.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid printing the false, use a `if (mysql_num_rows($friendlook))` (in the $friendlook part) to check whether there are results before trying to print anything.

If there are no results, **nothing will be printed**. and you won’t have that annoying issue.

Performance note: Don’t use **print**, use **echo** instead.

Comment: Is there any difference between print/echo at all? I was told to use print rather than echo. ;)

Comment: @RussellHarrower print returns a boolean true, echo has no return value. It will save CPU time and increase performance on heavily used scripts.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please remove that downvote. You downvote when the answer is not useful, not when you don’t understand a part of it. Which also did not have much to do with the solution itself. The solution I gave actually works.

Comment: @Mario - Even if you are printing in a loop of 100000, you won't be able to tell there is a difference in execution time. So i would place this advice at the end of the answer, at the moment one could mean that is the cause of the error.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe you want to use something like

```
public function friendsOutputAsJSON($userid)
{
    $this->userid = $userid;
    $result = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            friend.to_userid,
            info.username, info.firstname, info.lastname, info.status,
            astatus.onlinestatus
        FROM
            user_contact as friend
        LEFT JOIN
            user_info as info
        ON
            friend.to_userid = info.id
        LEFT JOIN
            user_online as astatus
        ON
            friend.to_userid = astatus.userid
        WHERE
            friend.to_userid = info.id
            AND friend.from_userid = '". mysql_real_escape_string($userid). "'
            AND friend.approved = 1
        ORDER BY
            astatus.onlinestatus DESC
    ");
    if ( !$result ) {
        yourErrorHandler();
    }

    $rows = array();
    while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    if( empty($rows) )
    {
        $rows = array("error" => "No Friends?<br/>Search above for New users or invite some friends.");
    }
    print json_encode($arr);
}
```

i.e.

- not performing an extra query to check if there are any records (which should use Count(*) if you want to keep it)
- fetch all records, instead of only the first
- checking if some records have been fetched instead using mysql_num_rows
- having only one return/print "exit point" for the function
- (possibly preventing sql injections - depends on what $userid can be/how it is checked before calling the function)

Answer (score 0):

i think json_encode() fails .

i advice you to check the error type :

```
  switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }
```